# Blockchain.info returns "None Standard Script Output" when submitting a transaction?

Tags: bitcore

I dont know what is wrong

```
var insight = new Insight('https://insight.bitpay.com','livenet');
insight.getUnspentUtxos('1MkZVyKqNB5jpJDpfhp4TkDikFwdQM44he', function(err, utxos) {

if (err) {
        console.log('Error in getUnspentUtxos: ' + err);
    } else {
        console.log('utxos' + ' :' + JSON.stringify(utxos, undefined, 2));

        var transaction = new bitcore.Transaction()
        .from(utxos)
        .addData('pime')// Add OP_RETURN data.
        .to('1J4u97VGMz4GV7YFfRjtKLDchZ5zjiKLu4',15000)
        .fee(1000)
        .change('1AG1c1t3FAAEFdxmzm3wTg7XAnRGSwX5QA')
        .sign(privateKey);

        console.log(transaction.serialize());

        //console.log(transaction);

    }
});
```

This is the result: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=YNaHBcmU

Comment: blockchain.info does not accept OP_RETURN outputs via API, You should use any other service for broadcasting. for example http://webbtc.com/relay_tx

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with this transaction, the website you tried to submit it through (blockchain.info) is defective. I have broadcast it for you, and it is visible as a confirmed transaction on [most](https://www.blocktrail.com/BTC/tx/63913178feb485db6f25c9f7940e3d17175ae7a51bf1ae58acf8f11ee95a2966) [block](https://btc.blockr.io/tx/info/63913178feb485db6f25c9f7940e3d17175ae7a51bf1ae58acf8f11ee95a2966) [explorers](https://insight.bitpay.com/tx/63913178feb485db6f25c9f7940e3d17175ae7a51bf1ae58acf8f11ee95a2966).

`bitcoin-cli decoderawtransaction` is a useful tool which will let you decode and view the transaction have created prior to submitting it to the network, and `bitcoin-cli sendrawtransaction` will allow you to broadcast the transaction without relying on possibly faulty third parties.

```
{
  "txid": "63913178feb485db6f25c9f7940e3d17175ae7a51bf1ae58acf8f11ee95a2966",
  "version": 1,
  "locktime": 0,
  "vin": [
    {
      "txid": "f713e91b7df1dc4e4e85c7e2d9a050ca95408d1f578925f54aa93dc7bc98daa7",
      "vout": 0,
      "scriptSig": {
        "asm": "3044022012051ad672731cf555964c23d31defb67b06a85ea7de4843777d7058d3a084490220567864bf79669a8cb48e8de29f31fb29caef56f741ab9145424b3430af7b317001 038042cf5da3747c559e1d77e574eb81842958ef0cbc0461c1b783eda091afa782",
        "hex": "473044022012051ad672731cf555964c23d31defb67b06a85ea7de4843777d7058d3a084490220567864bf79669a8cb48e8de29f31fb29caef56f741ab9145424b3430af7b31700121038042cf5da3747c559e1d77e574eb81842958ef0cbc0461c1b783eda091afa782"
      },
      "sequence": 4294967295
    }
  ],
  "vout": [
    {
      "value": 0.00000000,
      "n": 0,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "OP_RETURN 1701669232",
        "hex": "6a0470696d65",
        "type": "nulldata"
      }
    },
...
}
```

Comment: so..I need to put sendrawtransaction..for example get the rawtransaction and then sendrawtransaction. can i use rpc json to use node and bitcoind??

Comment: Basically use any raw transaction submission method that is not Blockchain.info. The RPC interface of `bitcoind` will work fine, and there is surely tools existing to communicate with it.